# Immature lawn mushroom

Tags: mycology

These have been popping up all over our yard in South Western Australia. I have been digging them out before they mature as I have small children. But with 7 acres I can only check so much.
My question is: Is it possible to eliminate them as being harmful mushrooms from this picture before seeing them at maturity?

Some have been growing in isolation, others in clusters.

Note: a few weeks ago, from near this spot, I removed a white mushroom on a stem with its cap still closed and white gills when I opened it. I have also found a few different types of puffballs around[image]

Comment: Are you able to obtain an additional photograph of the stipe (stem) of the fungus? If not, may you please describe the properties of its gills and hymenium - cells which eventually produce spores?

Comment: To get a good answer you will need to observe the growth of the mushrooms and post pictures at different stages. Puffball mushrooms will "pop" when poked releasing a cloud of spores. Some mushrooms look like a puffball when young but then open like an umbrella later.